# Is there a limit to number of lights in CYCLES?

Tags: modeling, memory-management

I was making a scene using very few lights along with Nishita Sky Texture. The total emissive lights used are - 2 Area lights + 1 icoshpere with Emission shader + Nishita Sky Texture. Just adding one extra light my scene stopped rendering in viewport and in Render window I am getting message "Out of Memory". What do I need to do ti fix this?

Comment: That's a hardware limitation, your pc can handle more than that

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a limit, but generally, you can have as many lights in your scene as you want with Cycles. That's quite easy to test:

[image]

The problem is not because you have too many lights but because there is no more memory on you PC for your render device to use. So if you are using CPU rendering, there is no more RAM, if it's GPU, there is not enough VRAM for your scene. Large textures usually use a lot of memory but particles and dense geometry can also lead to this situation. When you use the same GPU for display and rendering it might be that the memory gets full, but if you restart Blender, you might still be able to render the scene. Note that other software also use memory even if it's VRAM. A lot of programs use GPU acceleration these days, so it might be a good idea to close other applications.

Comment: Right now I am so damn jealous of your PC. I have a poor GPU but I got 16 Gigs of RAM. Also I would like to add. After qutting Blender and restarting PC that limit seems to have resolved. I can add more lights now. (I just checked today after posting this question). So could this be a bug because I was not using any other software while using Blender yesterday.

Comment: @NewBlenderer -- here's where you may want to consider a farm for your rendering, where others contribute their PCs with greater capabilities.  I contribute and sometimes render large projects on "sheepit-renderfarm.com".  You'll want to lend your own PC resource to build up points; otherwise you'll be waiting "back of the line" for future renderings.

Comment: I can't farm, neither i can contribute. I feel my laptop or Blender behaves randomly. My scene was very low intensity with nothing much going on. I do feel it's a bug in either windows 10 or Blender itself

Comment: If it says it's out of memory, chances are it is simply out of memory, no bugs required for that. What are the specs of the laptop? Does it meet [the minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?